# Keras doesn't seem to correctly load a trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Following along with a tutorial to learn keras i've hit a bit of a snag. 
 i have some code to solve the lunar lander problem, which seems to train the agent up and get pretty good scores after many iterations of training (eg for the Lunar lander problem hes getting scores between 200 - 400 usually), but when i load in the trained model its like he starts all over.  Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if keras is , really need some advice here.

At the bottom i've included some of the final scores its getting , then some of the scores its getting when i rerun

```
import random
import os
import gym
import numpy as np
from collections import deque
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam

EPISODES = 1000

class DQNAgent:
def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
    self.state_size = state_size
    self.action_size = action_size
    self.memory = deque(maxlen=2000)
    self.gamma = 0.95    # discount rate
    self.epsilon = 1.0  # exploration rate
    self.epsilon_min = 0.01
    self.epsilon_decay = 0.995
    self.learning_rate = 0.001
    self.model = self._build_model()

def _build_model(self):
    # Neural Net for Deep-Q learning Model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mse',
                  optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
    return model

def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
    self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

def act(self, state):
    if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:
        return random.randrange(self.action_size)
    act_values = self.model.predict(state)
    return np.argmax(act_values[0])  # returns action

def replay(self, batch_size):
    minibatch = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)
    for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:
        target = reward
        if not done:
            target = (reward + self.gamma *
                      np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0]))
        target_f = self.model.predict(state)
        target_f[0][action] = target
        self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
    if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
        self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay

def load(self, name):
    #self.model.load(name)
pass
def save(self, name):
    self.model.save(name)


#if __name__ == "__main__":
loaded = False
env = gym.make('LunarLander-v2')
state_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]
action_size = env.action_space.n
agent = DQNAgent(state_size, action_size)
# agent.load("./save/cartpole-dqn.h5")
if os.path.exists('cart_save.h5') == True:
    #agent.model.load('cart_save.h5')
agent.model = load_model('cart_save.h5')
    loaded = False
done = False
batch_size = 32
print
print loaded
print

for e in range(EPISODES):
    state = env.reset()
    state = np.reshape(state, [1, state_size])
time_rec = -1
total_reward = 0
end = False
    #for time in range(500):
while not end:
    time_rec += 1
        # env.render()
        action = agent.act(state)
        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        #reward = reward if not done else -10
    total_reward += reward
        next_state = np.reshape(next_state, [1, state_size])
        agent.remember(state, action, total_reward, next_state, done)
        state = next_state
        if loaded:
        env.render()
        if done:
            print("episode: {}/{}, score: {}, e: {:.2}"
                  .format(e, EPISODES, total_reward, agent.epsilon))
            break
        if len(agent.memory) > batch_size:
            agent.replay(batch_size)

if done and e > 50 and agent.epsilon < .05 and total_reward > 200:
    agent.model.save("cart2_save.h5")
    print
    print "saved file"
    print


if e == 200:
    agent.model.save("cart_final.h5")

if e == 400:
    agent.model.save("cart_final.h5")

if e == 600:
    agent.model.save("cart_final.h5")

if e >= 1000:
    agent.model.save("cart_final.h5")
```

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

#Save the whole model
model.save('my_model.h5')
new_model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

Reference: https://jovianlin.io/saving-loading-keras-models/

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite old but maybe it can help someone else. I was having the same issue and actually realized it has nothing to do with loading the model.

The issue is this line:

```
def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
...
    self.epsilon = 1.0  # exploration rate
```

When you train, your epsilon is decreased at each episode so you have less exploration.
But if you instanciate a new agent and load the model, you have the correct model but a full exploration agent (epsilon=1).
When loading from a trained model, you need epsilon=0 as you are not doing any training anymore (or have a different inference function for prediction outside of training ignoring epsilon).

Another way to look at it is to realise that for predictions only (no training), you don't need an agent. You can use the model alone.

```
model = load_model("model_name.h5")
action = model.predict(state)
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you aren't loading what you think you're loading. Maybe I missed it, but the code you posted doesn't seem to include writing your trained model to disk so I'm not sure how the model you are loading got there. Additionally, you check for the existence of `cart_save.h5`, but then ignore that model and (try to) load `900.h5`. Per your outputs, it seems 900.h5 probably isn't the model you want to be trying to load.

It's a little hard to read your code because the indentation seems to have been messed up a bit. Also, are you using python 2? You should really, REALLY switch to python 3.

My recommendation is to move all of your saved models into a subdirectory your script doesn't know about like "./archive" or something like that and try re-running it fresh. That way you can be sure that the model you are loading is one that was a saved checkpoint produced by the most recent execution of the script, because it isn't clear to me that this is currently the case.

Comment: the training took so long that i ended up saving a lot of different versions as i went along based on iterations (eg i saved the model when it got to iteration 500, 900, etc).  But each time i loaded the model, and reran the agent it seemed to act as though it was completely new.  


I'll edit the code, but i was just trying different versions.  But regardless as to the version (saved .h5) i tried it always seemed to restart the entire training cycle and never actually used the trained brain.


If i wanted to apply a trained brain to any gym environment, what would be the code to do so ?

Comment: Edited the original code, realized that the ending bit hadnt gotten copied over for some reason.  I've been adjusting things a lot trying to solve this.  Can you take a look now and see what you think

Comment: Can you check your code again? I'm skeptical about your indentation, otherwise maybe that's part of the problem. E.g. you have a bunch of `e==` tests, but none of these are nested under the `for e in range(EPISODES)` loop, your `load` function isn't aligned with the `pass` call below it, etc. You would probably benefit from wrapping the code beneath your (commented out) `if __name__ == '__main__'` block in methods attached to a "Simulation" class or something like that to help clarify for yourself that it's all doing what you think it is. About half of your code is unorganized "script."